# How can I make an action after response from server?

Tags: react-native, redux, rxjs

I make an app using React Native, Redux and RxJS. Here you can find my epic code:

```
const MyEpic = (action$, store) =>
action$.pipe(
  ofType(ActionCreators.ACTION_ONE.type),
  mergeMap(action =>
        api.postRegister(action.payload)
        .map(res => ActionCreators.ACTION_TWO.create(res))
        .catch(err => Observable.of(ActionCreators.ACTION_FAILED.create(err)))
));
```

I have some problems with async actions. I get data from api, ACTION_TWO changes the state. What I want to get, is make another action, lets call id ACTION_THREE, after getting response from an api and after the ACTION_TWO update state. Do you have any clues how can I do it? Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Just make another effect where you map `ACTION_TWO` to `ACTION_THREE`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response!
I did: 
.map(res => ActionCreators.ACTION_TWO.create(res)
     .map(res => console.log('test));
)

And I get an error: _index.ActionCreators.ACTION_TWO.create(...).map is not a function.

:/

Comment: Well, I don't know what your `.create(res)` returns

Comment: Don't `map`, `tap` instead. You're not mapping anything.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```js
const myEpic = actions$ => actions$.pipe(
  ofType(ActionCreators.ACTION_TWO.type),
  concatMap(action => api.makeSomeRequest()), // assuming Observable is returned from "api" method
  map(response => /* create ACTION_THREE */)
)
```

This will make api request **every time** `ACTION_TWO` is dispatched and return `ACTION_THREE` after it